# SQL SELECT Returning the same value twice in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, select, gridview

Good Day All,

So I'm working on a small application that stores entries into a table (author, short description of paper/book) and then metadata (user's vote, ID of entry, User ID, and comments). I have things working using JOIN's to get the information that I want displayed according to the user who is logged in, "1".

The catch is that I'm running into a weird bug where because there are multiple metadata rows about a single entry, the entry itself is being displayed multiple times. IE I have 2 reviews on a single entry and the entry itself is showing up twice in my GridView.

I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

.cs

```
string id = "1";
DbConn dbConn = new DbConn();

SQL = "SELECT * FROM ec.dbo.entry e INNER JOIN ec.dbo.metadata m
ON e.eID = m.eID WHERE m.uID='"+ id + "'";
ds = new DataSet();
ds = dbConn.createDataSet(SQL);
results.DataSource = ds;
results.DataBind();

string SQL3 = "SELECT * FROM ec.dbo.entry e RIGHT JOIN
ec.dbo.metadata m ON m.eID = e.eID WHERE m.uID <> '" + id + "' OR m.uID IS NULL
OR m.eID IS NULL";
dsPending = new DataSet();
dsPending = dbConn.createDataSet(SQL3);
pending.DataSource = dsPending;
pending.DataBind();
```

[image: Screenshot of Duplication of Data]

When a user clicks yes or no then the entry has metadata created depending on the user logged in. Then this select command is run and is only supposed to pull information this way:

1.) If user is logged in; check to see if they have any meta data and pull the entries that have said metadata attached into the first GridView

2.) If there is no metadata associated to the entries and the user logged in, then display all entries in second GridView that have not been voted on(metadata created).

3.) When voted on, the entry should not show up in second GridView and only be displayed in the first GridView .

If this doesn't make sense let me know and I can try to clarify better.

So as you can see the 'MotoX' entry is being duplicated. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I've made a few changes and took a step forward in removing the duplicates but in the process now its displaying all of my entries rather than just ones that have no metadata associated to the logged in user.

.cs

```
string SQL3 = "SELECT * FROM ec.dbo.entry e 
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 'X' from ec.dbo.metadata m
where m.eID = e.eID and (m.uID <> '' OR m.uID IS NULL));";
dsPending = new DataSet();
SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL3, dbconn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
pending.DataSource = dt;
pending.DataBind();
```

photo
[image: Not duplicating, but now just displaying all entries]

Comment: Have you confirmed in debug that only a single row is being returned from sql server?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I think what is happening is that there are multiple metadata rows that have a vote (yes/no) from different users that are not logged in as the current user. I need to only display 'entries' that user himself has not voted on(metadata).

Comment: Oops didn't finish my first sentence. Because there are multiple metadata entries, the entry itself is getting displayed multiple times.

Comment: Can you try putting the where condition in sql3 in brackets to see if that makes a difference i.e. WHERE( m.uID <> '" + id + "' OR m.uID IS NULLOR m.eID IS NULL)";, and i know this is a cop out but can you also put select distinct in sql 3

Comment: @sa1986 Brackets didn't do anything. Going to try distinct next.

Comment: DISTINCT didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, your `metadata` table have 2 record for one record in `entry` table .
So simple fix is by adding a `distinct` to entry record.
Else try the `EXISTS` query below.

```
 SELECT * FROM EnglishConference.dbo.entry e 
WHERE EXISTS
( SELECT 'X' from ec.dbo.metadata m 
   where m.eID = e.eID and  (m.uID <> '<YOUR_ID>' OR m.uID IS NULL));
```

Sorry, i use ipad, not easy to type :(

Comment: Adding DISTINCT didn't do anything. And yes my metadata table does have multiple records for the entry table. What I'm trying to do is to only display the records from the entry table that the Current user hasn't created any metadata. This being while there are other users creating there own records on the metadata table.

Comment: when i was about to complete, i posted unknowingly, as in iPad difficult to edit posts with formatting! please find now.

Comment: Oh not a problem. I'll give this a try and see if I can come up with anything!

Comment: Alright I got the code kind of working but now it's displaying all of the entries in the bottom table. (But no longer duplicating, so that's a step forward) I'll update with a photo in my question.

Comment: It should not duplicate, I edited the brackets.. `where m.eID = e.eID and  (m.uID <> '' OR m.uID IS NULL)`

Comment: I just updated with an edit and a screenshot. For some reason now it's removed the functionality of "If an entry has metadeta from the user, then it doesn't get displayed in the second GridView." Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Nevermind, I'm just struggling with code today. in the m.uID <> '' part I needed to define the user's log in ID. Everything seems to be working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear, also mind he brackets now.. it matters a lot now!! may not be serious in your right join query. Good Day!

Answer (score 0):

Even distinct will fetch two records. He has two distinct records already I am sure and I think the column on which he is joining definitely is not the unique key.